# Fabric.js, Darkroom.js, and devicePixelRatio offset

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I asked this on the Darkroom.js GitHub page, but it doesn't appear as though it's particularly active, so I'm asking here as well.  Overall this has been a great plugin, but I'm having issues after having done some testing on a Retina screen.

On a browser where the devicePixelRatio is 1, everything works great.  On higher values, I get this as result :

[image]

After testing, I noticed this issue was present in other areas on the site, where I hadn't used darkroom.js, but just Fabric.js or Standard Canvas.  Doing some research led me to finding :

```
var c = canvas.getElement();
var w = c.width, h = c.height;
c.setAttribute('width', w * window.devicePixelRatio);
c.setAttribute('height', h * window.devicePixelRatio);
c.getContext('2d').scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
```

Which appears to fix thing in those cases.

With darkroom.js however, I've had no such luck in finding a fix.  Has anyone experienced this issue or similar, and are there any known solutions?  I'm using the latest version found here : http://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will be particularly helpful to anyone else, but maybe it'll save someone some time.

After going back to this, and making a number of changes to Darkroom.js, I found my changes caused problems in other areas (such as cropping) and it wasn't worth sorting out.  Switching to using version 1.5 for Fabric.js actually solved the problems I was seeing in Darkroom, even though on its own Fabric.js 1.6 worked fine.  Version 1.5 worked throughout, so I stuck with that.